# parsing templates at compile time

Tags: go

In my understanding, go templates are parsed from a given source at runtime in order to get a compiled version of type template.Template. Then, the compiled version is executed on some data to do the actual templating.

But then I'm wondering : is it possible to parse a template at compile time ?

Comment: No, but you can parse them once when starting the application and cache them for reuse.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make them global variables [like this](http://play.golang.org/p/AAS9pEpjde).  You'll still parse the templates at run time but it will be immediately so the binary will fail as soon as you run it if it can't parse them properly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

var t = template.Must(template.New("name").Parse("text"))

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Template", t)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

can't do it at compile time, but you can parse them at runtime before `main()` by parsing them inside [the init function](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init).

Comment: This is how I would do it too. The init() function seems great for doing setup related things like compiling/caching templates, setting up database connections and doing anything else you would want done before the app is available for use.